# Laplace Transform: Product of Bessel Functions

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

I'm trying to find the closed form solution for the integral of the product of Bessel functions. Namely,

$$
I_{\alpha \beta}
=
\int_{0}^{\infty}
dT
e^{-2s T}
J_{\alpha}(T) J_{\beta}(T)
$$
where $s > 0$ is a real number and $\alpha, \beta$ are positive integers. Any help you would greatly appreciated! (Even the case where $\alpha = \beta$ would be good).

Comment: We have
$$J_\alpha(t) J_\beta(t) =
\frac
 {\Gamma {\left( \frac {\alpha + \beta + 1} 2 \right)}
  \Gamma {\left( \frac {\alpha + \beta +2} 2 \right)}}
 {\sqrt \pi \, \Gamma(\alpha + 1) \Gamma(\beta + 1) \Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 1)}
t^{\alpha + \beta} \times \\
{_2 F_3} {\left(
 \frac {\alpha + \beta + 1} 2, \frac {\alpha + \beta + 2} 2;
 \alpha + 1, \beta + 1, \alpha + \beta + 1;
 -t^2 \right)}.$$
Taking the Laplace transform of $t^{2 k + a}$ and expanding  $\Gamma(2 k + a + 1)$ gives a ${_4 F_3}$ function.

Answer (score 3):

Identity 10.22.66 on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#iv) states:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-a t}J_\nu(bt)J_\nu(ct)\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{bc}}Q_{\nu-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2bc}\right)$$
With $Q_n$ being the [associated Legendre function of the second kind](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3#ii) of order $n$. So in the case that $\alpha=\beta$, your integral should be
$$\frac{1}{\pi}Q_{\beta-\frac{1}{2}}\left(2s^2+1\right)$$
I'm not sure what to do about the $\alpha\neq \beta $ case. Perhaps we can start with the smaller of the two and then make multiple uses of the recurrence
$$J_{\nu+1}(z)=\frac{2\nu}{z}J_\nu(z)-J_{\nu-1}(z)$$
But I doubt this helps much.